# Check column value in 4 different table with specific ID and return pass of fail

Tags: php, mysql

Tabel_1:

```
Id    test_id  testname    passfail
1      1001       test1      pass
2      1001       test2      fail
3      1002       test11     pass
4      1002       test12     pass
5      1003       test21     fail
6      1003       test22     fail
```

Tabel_2:

```
Id    test_id  testname    passfail
1      1001       test1      pass
2      1001       test2      pass
3      1001       test3      pass
4      1002       test11     pass
6      1002       test13     fail
7      1002       test13     fail
```

Tabel_3:

```
Id    test_id  testname    passfail
4      1002       test11     pass
5      1002       test12     pass
6      1003       test31     fail
7      1003       test32     fail
```

Tabel_4:

```
Id    test_id  testname    passfail
1      1001       test1      pass
2      1001       test2      pass
3      1001       test3      pass
4      1003       test11     pass
5      1003       test12     pass
```

I want to check passfail column in all table(Tabel_1, Tabel_2, Tabel_3, Tabel_4) with specific test_id like 1001 or any test_id. if any of row has fail for passfail column belong to id like 1001 then query will be returned only once fail or no fail found in passfail column belong that specific test_id then query will be returned only once pass from passfail colomn.

Comment: Bad database structure.:(

Comment: yes it is you must learn about database structure and relationship

Comment: ya...i know...but this 4 table for 4 different types of  test group...and each group has many test

Comment: what you actually want to do ...???

Comment: any of test_id like (1001,1002,1003 ..)of any table has fail in passfail column...then test will be fail

Comment: and all pass in passfail column for specific test_id  (1001,1002, 1003) then test will be pass...

Comment: if i get fail/pass then i will save it to another table with test_id

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression like this:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM Table1
                       WHERE test_Id = 1001 AND passfail = 'fail'
                       UNION 
                       SELECT 1
                       FROM Table2
                       WHERE test_Id = 1001 AND passfail = 'fail'
                       UNION 
                       SELECT 1
                       FROM Table3
                       WHERE test_Id = 1001 AND passfail = 'fail'
                       UNION 
                       SELECT 1
                       FROM Table4
                       WHERE test_Id = 1001 AND passfail = 'fail')
           THEN 'fail'
           ELSE 'pass'
         END AS flag;
```

This `SELECT` statement returns *always* a single row: if there is at least one row in any of the four tables having `passfail = 'fail'` then 'fail' is returned, otherwise 'pass' is returned.

Comment: Thanks..I got my desire result... just i need another help

Comment: i am almost new...in development in php mysql..i am using in codeigniter MVC..how i can return flag variable

Comment: @Asif This is a different question. I have no knowledge of codeigniter. So, why don't you try writing another question?

Comment: I need another help...If any table has no test_Id = 1001 then result will be  no record.

Comment: @Asif I'm afraid I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the result of each `SELECT` by using [UNION DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

```
SELECT test_id FROM Table_1 WHERE passfail = 'fail'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT test_id FROM Table_2 WHERE passfail = 'fail'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT test_id FROM Table_3 WHERE passfail = 'fail'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT test_id FROM Table_4 WHERE passfail = 'fail'
```

Comment: if i will pass any of test_id ...then may be where condition need  ?? and query need to returned only once pass of fail

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment correctly. If you want to check one special test_id, you have to add `AND test_id = 1234` to each select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine result by [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) and use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for grouping by some field:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
  SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM t4 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
) as t
GROUP BY test_id;
```

Result:

```
1   1001    test1   pass
4   1002    test12  pass
8   1003    test32  pass
3   10015   test11  pass
```

If you will add test_id to SELECT statement you will get only ids:

```
SELECT test_id FROM
  (
  SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM t4 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
) as t
GROUP BY test_id;
```

Result: `1001, 1002, 1003, 10015`

Also you can get all rows with `pass` value if remove [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
  SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM t3 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM t4 WHERE passfail = 'pass'
) as t;
```

Result:

```
1   1001    test1   pass
3   10015   test11  pass
4   1002    test12  pass
2   1001    test2   pass
3   1001    test3   pass
4   1002    test11  pass
1   1002    test11  pass
2   1002    test12  pass
5   1001    test11  pass
6   1001    test12  pass
7   1001    test31  pass
8   1003    test32  pass
9   1003    test13  pass
```